# Unity Errors creating New Project or Opening Old

Tags: unity-game-engine

This has been going on for 2 days, I've been trying to fix it but nothing works. Don't even suggest for me to delete any cache folders in Unity because I've deleted and re-installed like all of them.

[error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLolv.png)

I get this on every project new or old now, I've gone to the scripts and tried to make edits but nothing works. I've uninstalled unity and re-installed, nothing works. Already tried re-installing all project files and regenerating. Does anyone know how to help? I really don't want to move out of the Unity engine right now. Please help me guys.

[Just to show the project in-case im missing something.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwKSD.png)

I've also tried switching editors and code editors. Nothing works. Someone has to know how to fix this.

Comment: This happens even in a new empty project?

Comment: Yeah unfortuantly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in one of the standard Unity packages. If it’s happening even in a new empty project, and you don’t have any other custom packages installed that might be incompatible with it, it’d seem either Unity messed something up or the files were altered or corrupted somehow.

Go to **Window -> Package Manager** and try removing and then reinstalling the **2D Sprite** package under the **Packages: Unity Registry** tab.

If that doesn’t help, and you upgraded Unity before you started experiencing the issue, try backing up your project and then upgrading or downgrading to another Unity version.

Comment: I've already tried this to no result 

Comment: Pretty weird :/. Have you tried installing a different Unity version? Is there a need to stay on 2020 or would 2021 be a possibility? It entered LTS recently.

Comment: I have switched versions before

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t think of a reason clean installs of diverse Unity versions would exhibit this issue in empty projects on your machine but not other machines.